# Expired date calculation

Tags: php, date

I have found the code below on the site to calculate due date. This function seems to work on the actual day and gives me the due date based on $months. How could I use that function but base on my defined date instead. So meaning, If I enter $myday = 2013-01-01, I want the function to tell me that it is due every month (if I select Monthly of course) and in how many days it is due compared to the TODAY date. So for example, if we are January 31 2015 and I launch the function, it should tell me that the due date is in 1 day because it's every month the due date.

```
function calculate_postpone_due_date($billingcycle) {
    switch ($billingcycle) {
        case "Monthly":
            $months = 1;
            break;
        case "Quarterly":
            $months = 3;
            break;
        case "Semi-Annually":
            $months = 6;
            break;
        case "Annually":
            $months = 12;
            break;
        case "Biennially":
            $months = 24;
            break;
        case "Triennially":
            $months = 36;
            break;
        default:
            $months = 0;
            break;
    }

    if ($months == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $today         = date('Y-m-d');
    $next_due_date = strtotime($today . ' + ' . $months . ' Months');

    return date('Y-m-d', $next_due_date);
}
```

Comment: Add a date parameter to the function then replace the date passed to `strtotime` as today with said parameter.

Comment: Is this part of a class? If so what is it named?

Comment: So you want the function to return string "Monthly" and integer 1, am I reading you correctly?

Comment: Actually, this is not really what I need it to to. Let say I have a payment every month and this is happening from 2001-01-01. So every month from that date I have a recurring payment. But when i'm on 2013-09-04, the next recuring date should be 2013-10-10. So how to have that as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send date in function then it will work take look at below code hope useful

```
function calculate_postpone_due_date($billingcycle,$date)
{
switch($billingcycle)
{
    case "Monthly":         $months = 1; break;
    case "Quarterly":       $months = 3; break;
    case "Semi-Annually":   $months = 6; break;
    case "Annually":        $months = 12; break;
    case "Biennially":      $months = 24; break;
    case "Triennially":     $months = 36; break;
    default:                $months = 0; break;
}


if ($months == 0)
    return FALSE;    

$today = $date;
$next_due_date = strtotime($today.' + '.$months.' Months');
return date('Y-m-d', $next_due_date);

}
echo  calculate_postpone_due_date($billingcycle,'your date')
```

Comment: Actually, this is not really what I need it to to. Let say I have a payment every month and this is happening from 2001-01-01. So every month from that date I have a recurring payment. But when i'm on 2013-09-04, the next recuring date should be 2013-10-10. So how to have that as answer?

Answer (score 1):

Added new param `$date`. If you pass `$date` param, it'll get today.

```
function calculate_postpone_due_date($billingcycle, $date = false)
{
    switch($billingcycle)
    {
        case "Monthly":         $months = 1; break;
        case "Quarterly":       $months = 3; break;
        case "Semi-Annually":   $months = 6; break;
        case "Annually":        $months = 12; break;
        case "Biennially":      $months = 24; break;
        case "Triennially":     $months = 36; break;
        default:                $months = 0; break;
    }


    if ($months == 0)
        return FALSE;    

    $current = $date ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)) : date('Y-m-d');
    $next_due_date = strtotime($current.' + '.$months.' Months');
    return date('Y-m-d', $next_due_date);
}

echo calculate_postpone_due_date("Quarterly", "2013-01-01");
```

#### Output for 2013-01-01

```
2013-04-01
```

Comment: Actually, this is not really what I need it to to. Let say I have a payment every month and this is happening from 2001-01-01. So every month from that date I have a recurring payment. But when i'm on 2013-09-04, the next recuring date should be 2013-10-10. So how to have that as answer?

Comment: @seby `calculate_postpone_due_date("Monthly", "2013-09-04");` result is `2013-10-04`. I couldnt understand exactly what you want. Could you give me more detailed example please?

Comment: hello sir, well lets say you have a regular payment from 2001-01-01 of 100$. Then every month from that date I need a kind of reminder. so the answer is from today, when is the next payment date. the first of the next month. I don't know if i'm clearer?

Comment: @seby Lets say: `2001-01-01` is first payment day. Next month `2001-02-01` is it right? I understand that you have only first date like `2001-01-01`. your question is how to get this billing date after `12 years later ;)`? Right? You can update payment row `created 2001-01-01`, `updated 2001-02-01`. Every month, you can get `updated` column then run the function with `updated column`.

Comment: You mean, every time the function is run, I update the column with a new date? But the function will not necessaraly be run on the right day. How can I manage that?

Comment: no no, you wont update same column. For ex: you have `created` column. Now create new column as named `last_billing`. Each running this function, update to new created column with next billing or current billing time. And now you can give the `last_billing` column to function and you're getting +1 month from last_billing. So you should have two column. `created` and `updated` or `last_billing` something like that. Did you understand? Otherwise your getting next billing time after years years later, so diffucult. You should store them somewhere.

Comment: Ok I see, I think i'm gonna do this.